# How to stop gesture swiping back to previous view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, view, transition

In one of my view controllers I have a carousel that the user can swiper through.
But if the user swipes up in the top left hand corner of the screen they can drag back the previous view controller.

How can I stop this? It could be something to do with this?

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.carousel setHidden:YES];
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.carousel setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer

Set the interactivePopGestureRecognizer's enabled property to NO on your UINavigationController

Comment: But interactivePopGestureRecognizer is _readonly_ property of UINavigationController..

Comment: But the `enabled` property on `UIGestureRecognizer` isn't readonly... readonly means that you cannot set the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` to another instance but you can modify its properties (providing they are readwrite)